# Join has cross-product in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I am trying to come up with a trivial minimal functional example of a federated query not using any web interface or something, but a local query engine (in my case AG free tier).

Now this at least doesn't throw any errors and returns stuff, but I'm getting a warning that the query contains a cross-product. Now I guess the problem is that there is nothing that actually relates the results from the two endpoints.

```
join has cross-product. Unique LHS variables: ?actor_1_1, ?birthDate, ?spouseURI_1_2, ?spouseName; Unique RHS variables ?actor_2_1, ?gender
```

But how do I relate them then? In a generic manner, since I guess this information needs to be passed to the query-resolver, and eventually I'll query other databases.

```
PREFIX dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?birthDate ?spouseName ?gender {
  { SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql>
    { SELECT ?birthDate ?spouseName WHERE {
        ?actor rdfs:label "Arnold Schwarzenegger"@en ;
               dbpo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
               dbpo:spouse ?spouseURI .
        ?spouseURI rdfs:label ?spouseName .
        FILTER ( lang(?spouseName) = "en" )
      }
    }
  }

  { SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql>
    { SELECT ?gender WHERE {
      ?actor wdt:P1559 "Arnold Alois Schwarzenegger"@de .
      ?actor wdt:P21 ?gender .
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help here, I haven't had as hard a time getting into a subject since forever.

Comment: you "relate them" if they share some variables. Currently the result is useless, one endpoint returns birth date and spouse name, the other endpoint returns the gender. But how should the query engine know which belong together? I mean, this issue should be quite obvious, no? You know that it "should" doesn't matter here because you know the the labels from both data sources most likely is sufficient. But what if there are multiple entities with the same label? Long story short, a common identifier is necessary. In DBpedia there is the Wikidata ID via `owl:sameAs` available. This could be used

Comment: but this might not exists for all Wikidata entities.

Comment: Yeah ... I mean, that is basically what I was saying and asking about.
I figured they share the variable actor, but apparently that doesn't work out, but I can't exactly tell why, because I'm very uncertain about scoping rules in SPARQL.

"a common identifier is necessary" - I figure, but how do I accomplish that? And also, what do I do if a database does not have ```owl:sameAs```?

Comment: ok, they share `?actor` in each query pattern but you do not select those `?actor` bindings, that's why it's a cartesian. So only the projected variables are in scope of the outer query. Indeed, the URIs for `?actor` are different here in DBpedia and Wikidata. And you can't rely on labels in general, they are not always unique obviously. The only way is to make use of some existing links (here via `owl:sameAs`

Comment: - if such information does not exists indeed you have to apply the whole entity linking process which is non-trivial. That means, based on a sufficient amount of data you have to identify which actors URIs denote the same real world entity. This is indeed research topic and not 100% solvable

Comment: In your current example indeed you could use your own URI and pass it to both `SERVICE` queries such they are just returned. Like `{ SELECT (<http://example.org/Arnold_Schwarzenegger> as ?id) ?gender WHERE {` and `SELECT (<http://example.org/Arnold_Schwarzenegger> as ?id) ?birthDate ?spouseName WHERE {` - but as I said, this is clearly error prone given that there can be multiple different entities with the same label.

Comment: You can make use of `owl:sameAs` here with `SELECT ?birthDate ?spouseName ?wdID WHERE {
        ?actor rdfs:label "Arnold Schwarzenegger"@en ;
               dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
               dbo:spouse ?spouseURI ;
owl:sameAs ?wdID .
filter(strstarts(str(?wdID), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/"))
        ?spouseURI rdfs:label ?spouseName .
        FILTER ( lang(?spouseName) = "en" )
      }` - note, you could also omit the filetr on the Wikidata URI to get all links to other datasets. It will later on join just the correct ID only

Comment: and `SELECT ?gender (?actor AS wdID) WHERE {
      ?actor wdt:P1559 "Arnold Alois Schwarzenegger"@de .
      ?actor wdt:P21 ?gender .
      }`

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation!
You could have just as well written this as an answer, then I'd mark it as accepted.